# Google Map DrawingManager: How to Delete a Created Shape (ex. circle)?

Tags: reactjs

How can I delete a created shape in Google Map `DrawingManager`?

```
  <DrawingManager
          // defaultDrawingMode={google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.}
          defaultOptions={{
            drawingControl: true,
            drawingControlOptions: {
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
              drawingModes: [
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                // google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
                // google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
              ],
            },
            circleOptions: {
              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
              strokeOpacity: 0.8,
              strokeWeight: 2,
              fillColor: '#FF0000',
              fillOpacity: 0.35,
              draggable: true,
              editable: true,
            },
            polygonOptions: {
              strokeColor: '#FF0000',
              strokeOpacity: 1.0,
              strokeWeight: 3,
              fillColor: '#FF0000',
              fillOpacity: 0.3,
              draggable: true,
              editable: true,
            },
          }}
          onOverlayComplete={this.handleOverlayComplete}
        />
```

When creating an shape via drawing manager (google map), after creating it, I want to delete that one but I'm having difficulties on that one.
ReactJS

Comment: I would advice to include some code into your question. It will increase the chances of you getting an answer and reduce the chances to have your question flagged and closed.

Comment: @acarlstein, sorry forgot to add the code.

Comment: this is the component which is called for drawing on the map shapes like circle and polygon but after drawing them i want to remove them, and i'am new with react and i saw some examples which did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manipulate drawn shapes the following approach could be considered:

introduce `shapes` variable to keep a reference to drawn shapes:

```
class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.shapes = [];
  }

  //...
}
```

once `overlaycomplete` event is triggered, save drawn shape:

```
handleOverlayComplete(e) {
    const shape = e.overlay;
    shape.type = e.type;
    google.maps.event.addListener(shape, "click", () => {
      this.toggleSelection(shape);
    });
    this.toggleSelection(shape);
    this.shapes.push(shape)
}
```

and finally drawn shapes could be deleted from map like this:

```
deleteShapes() {
   this.state.shapes.forEach(shape => shape.setMap(null));
}
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-a8x6zu) for your reference

> Note: in the provided demo *to delete shapes*:
>
> - select stop drawing mode by clicking hand cursor button
> - click map (outside bounds of shape)

Comment: Yes this one deletes all the shapes but how can i make it so i can be able to delete only one shape?